# Subscribe to exchange as separate function

Tags: ios, swift, rabbitmq

I use singleton pattern for RabbitMQ:

```
final class ServiceBus{

    static let Instance = ServiceBus()

    var conn: RMQConnection;
    var ch: RMQChannel;
    var clientExchange: RMQExchange;
    var clientQueue: RMQQueue;  

    private init() {
        let delegate = RMQConnectionDelegateLogger()
        self.conn = RMQConnection(uri: myUri, delegate: delegate)
        self.conn.start()
        self.ch = self.conn.createChannel()
        self.clientExchange = ch.direct("Client")
        self.clientQueue = ch.queue("", options: .exclusive)
    }
}
```

I also have a lot of pages and I need subscribe to exchange via my sessionID. I subscribe again at every ViewController now:

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        ServiceBus.Instance.clientQueue.bind(ServiceBus.Instance.clientExchange, routingKey: sessionID)
        ServiceBus.Instance.clientQueue.subscribe({(_ message: RMQMessage) -> Void in
            let message = String(data: message.body, encoding: .utf8)!        
            //...
        })
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()        
        ServiceBus.Instance.clientQueue.bind(ServiceBus.Instance.clientExchange, routingKey: sessionID)
        ServiceBus.Instance.clientQueue.subscribe({(_ message: RMQMessage) -> Void in
            let message = String(data: message.body, encoding: .utf8)!        
            //...
        })
    }
}
```

How can I create a separate function to subscribe for exchange and use the same seperate function at different ViewControllers?